# Create new row in data frame with the highest value in certain column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
structure(list(group = c("NS2A", "NS2A", "NS2A", "NS5", "NS5", 
"NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", 
"NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5"), tag = c("NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_1.0015", 
"NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_0.9404", "NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_1.0141", 
"NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.6323", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.4983", 
"NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.5331", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.3962", 
"NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.1411", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6646", 
"NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.0874", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6065", 
"NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.3789", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6322", 
"NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_3.2712", "NS5_A_to_C_Nonsynonymous_9276_2.8576", 
"NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.7555", "NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_1.9121", 
"NS5_A_to_C_Nonsynonymous_9276_5.1328", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6368"
), alt_freq_perc = c(1.0015, 0.9404, 1.0141, 2.6323, 2.4983, 
2.5331, 2.3962, 2.1411, 2.6646, 2.0874, 2.6065, 2.3789, 2.6322, 
3.2712, 2.8576, 2.7555, 1.9121, 5.1328, 2.6368), Pass = c("P1", 
"P7", "P12", "P0", "P0", "P1", "P1", "P3", "P3", "P5", "P5", 
"P7", "P7", "P10", "P10", "P10", "P12", "P12", "P12")), row.names = c(7915L, 
14378L, 16525L, 4192L, 4535L, 9904L, 10341L, 12239L, 12319L, 
13591L, 13680L, 14657L, 14720L, 15416L, 15435L, 15457L, 17443L, 
17498L, 17559L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would need a code that automatically detects which is the row with the highest value in column "alt_freq_perc" within each group in the "group" column. In this example would be row number 3 and row number 18.
Then it creates a new row with a value 0.100 higher then that original value in the higher row adding a random fake ID in the "tag column".

I did it by manually creating a df for each group in the "group" column and appending it but with many groups and values it is not optimal as you need to create many df.
This for example is for row number 3 in the first group:

```
dfA<-data.frame(tag="NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_1.1141",
alt_freq_perc=1.1141,
Pass="PA",
Rep="A",
col="white")

test_cir_A<-rbind(dfA,test_cir_A)
```

Desired Output:

```
structure(list(group = c("NS2A", "NS2A", "NS2A", "NS2A", "NS5", 
"NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", 
"NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5"), tag = c("NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_1.1141", 
"NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_1.0015", "NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_0.9404", 
"NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_1.0141", "NS5_A_to_C_Nonsynonymous_9276_5.5328", 
"NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.6323", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.4983", 
"NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.5331", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.3962", 
"NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.1411", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6646", 
"NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.0874", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6065", 
"NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.3789", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6322", 
"NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_3.2712", "NS5_A_to_C_Nonsynonymous_9276_2.8576", 
"NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.7555", "NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_1.9121", 
"NS5_A_to_C_Nonsynonymous_9276_5.1328", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6368"
), alt_freq_perc = c(1.1141, 1.0015, 0.9404, 1.0141, 5.2328, 
2.6323, 2.4983, 2.5331, 2.3962, 2.1411, 2.6646, 2.0874, 2.6065, 
2.3789, 2.6322, 3.2712, 2.8576, 2.7555, 1.9121, 5.1328, 2.6368
), Pass = c("PA", "P1", "P7", "P12", "PA", "P0", "P0", "P1", 
"P1", "P3", "P3", "P5", "P5", "P7", "P7", "P10", "P10", "P10", 
"P12", "P12", "P12")), row.names = c("1", "7915", "14378", "16525", 
"11", "4192", "4535", "9904", "10341", "12239", "12319", "13591", 
"13680", "14657", "14720", "15416", "15435", "15457", "17443", 
"17498", "17559"), class = "data.frame")
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Something like `dplyr::bind_rows(df, dplyr::summarize(df, alt_freq_perc = max(alt_freq_perc) + 0.1, .by = group))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_modify` from the `dplyr` package to add row per group.

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  group_modify(~add_row(.x, 
                        tag = sub("_[^_]+$", 
                                  paste0("_", max(.x$alt_freq_perc + 0.1)), 
                                  .x$tag[.x$alt_freq_perc == max(.x$alt_freq_perc)]
                                  ),
                        alt_freq_perc = max(.x$alt_freq_perc + 0.1), 
                        Pass = "PA")) |>
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 21 × 4
   group tag                                   alt_freq_perc Pass 
   <chr> <chr>                                         <dbl> <chr>
 1 NS2A  NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_1.0015         1.00  P1   
 2 NS2A  NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_0.9404         0.940 P7   
 3 NS2A  NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_1.0141         1.01  P12  
 4 NS2A  NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_1.1141         1.11  PA   
 5 NS5   NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.6323             2.63  P0   
 6 NS5   NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.4983             2.50  P0   
 7 NS5   NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.5331             2.53  P1   
 8 NS5   NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.3962             2.40  P1   
 9 NS5   NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.1411             2.14  P3   
10 NS5   NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6646             2.66  P3   
11 NS5   NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.0874             2.09  P5   
12 NS5   NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6065             2.61  P5   
13 NS5   NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.3789             2.38  P7   
14 NS5   NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6322             2.63  P7   
15 NS5   NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_3.2712             3.27  P10  
16 NS5   NS5_A_to_C_Nonsynonymous_9276_2.8576          2.86  P10  
17 NS5   NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.7555             2.76  P10  
18 NS5   NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_1.9121             1.91  P12  
19 NS5   NS5_A_to_C_Nonsynonymous_9276_5.1328          5.13  P12  
20 NS5   NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6368             2.64  P12  
21 NS5   NS5_A_to_C_Nonsynonymous_9276_5.2328          5.23  PA
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R we can do `split`, `lapply`, `transform` and "combine" (2x `rbind`):

```r
split(xyzzy, xyzzy$group) |>
  lapply(\(x) x[which.max(x[, "alt_freq_perc"]), ]) |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _) |>
  transform(alt_freq_perc = alt_freq_perc + .1, Pass = "PA",
            tag = paste0(gsub("_[^_]+$", "", tag), "_", alt_freq_perc + .1)) |>
  rbind(xyzzy) |>
  { \(.) .[order(.$group), ] }() |> # cosmectics
  `rownames<-`(NULL)  # cosmectics
```

gives

```r
   group                                   tag alt_freq_perc Pass
1   NS2A NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_1.1141        1.1141   PA
2   NS2A NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_1.0015        1.0015   P1
3   NS2A NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_0.9404        0.9404   P7
4   NS2A NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_1.0141        1.0141  P12
5    NS5  NS5_A_to_C_Nonsynonymous_9276_5.2328        5.2328   PA
6    NS5     NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.6323        2.6323   P0
7    NS5     NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.4983        2.4983   P0
8    NS5     NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.5331        2.5331   P1
9    NS5     NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.3962        2.3962   P1
10   NS5     NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.1411        2.1411   P3
11   NS5     NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6646        2.6646   P3
12   NS5     NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.0874        2.0874   P5
13   NS5     NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6065        2.6065   P5
14   NS5     NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.3789        2.3789   P7
15   NS5     NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6322        2.6322   P7
16   NS5     NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_3.2712        3.2712  P10
17   NS5  NS5_A_to_C_Nonsynonymous_9276_2.8576        2.8576  P10
18   NS5     NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.7555        2.7555  P10
19   NS5     NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_1.9121        1.9121  P12
20   NS5  NS5_A_to_C_Nonsynonymous_9276_5.1328        5.1328  P12
21   NS5     NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6368        2.6368  P12
```

---

Data:

```r
xyzzy = 
  structure(list(group = c("NS2A", "NS2A", "NS2A", "NS5", "NS5", 
                           "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", 
                           "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5", "NS5"), tag = c("NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_1.0015", 
                                                                       "NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_0.9404", "NS2A_C_to_A_Nonsynonymous_3931_1.0141", 
                                                                       "NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.6323", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.4983", 
                                                                       "NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.5331", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.3962", 
                                                                       "NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.1411", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6646", 
                                                                       "NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.0874", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6065", 
                                                                       "NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_2.3789", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6322", 
                                                                       "NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_3.2712", "NS5_A_to_C_Nonsynonymous_9276_2.8576", 
                                                                       "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.7555", "NS5_G_to_A_Synonymous_8561_1.9121", 
                                                                       "NS5_A_to_C_Nonsynonymous_9276_5.1328", "NS5_A_to_T_Synonymous_9728_2.6368"
                           ), alt_freq_perc = c(1.0015, 0.9404, 1.0141, 2.6323, 2.4983, 
                                                2.5331, 2.3962, 2.1411, 2.6646, 2.0874, 2.6065, 2.3789, 2.6322, 
                                                3.2712, 2.8576, 2.7555, 1.9121, 5.1328, 2.6368), Pass = c("P1", 
                                                                                                          "P7", "P12", "P0", "P0", "P1", "P1", "P3", "P3", "P5", "P5", 
                                                                                                          "P7", "P7", "P10", "P10", "P10", "P12", "P12", "P12")), row.names = c(7915L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                14378L, 16525L, 4192L, 4535L, 9904L, 10341L, 12239L, 12319L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                13591L, 13680L, 14657L, 14720L, 15416L, 15435L, 15457L, 17443L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                17498L, 17559L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `split`, `lapply` and `rbind`:

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df,df$group),function(x) 
 rbind(data.frame(group=x$group[1],tag=paste0(gsub("_[^_]+$", "_",
 x$tag[1]),max(x$alt_freq_perc)+0.1),alt_freq_perc=max(x$alt_freq_perc)+0.1,
 Pass="PA"),x)))
```